# Gradient of $X \mapsto \frac1{\sqrt{\det (X)}}$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, determinant, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

> Let $\Bbb S_n^{++}$ denote the set of $n \times n$ symmetric positive definite matrices over $\Bbb R$. Let scalar field $f : \Bbb S_n^{++} \to \Bbb R$ be defined by $$ f (X) := \frac1{\sqrt{\det(X)}} $$ Find the gradient $\nabla_X f$.

---

What I got was

$$\nabla_X f (X) = -\frac12\det(X)^{-\frac32} \operatorname{tr} \left( X^{-1} \right)$$

Is it correct? Full explanation, please.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gradient of the determinent is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula)
$$\eqalign{
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\p{\partial}\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
h &= \det(X) \qiq\grad hX = hX^{-T}
 \qquad\qquad\quad \\
}$$
Using this result, the gradient of your function becomes
$$\eqalign{
f &= h^{-1/2} \qiq \grad fX &= -\frac{1}2\:h^{-3/2}\gradLR hX \\
 &&= -\frac 12\:h^{-1/2}X^{-T} \\
}$$
The result that you derived is incorrect because it is scalar-valued, whereas a scalar-by-matrix gradient must be matrix-valued.